# Cannot find a way to update Joomla from 3.3.6

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, update, permissions

I have recently started doing some maintenance of a website managed by Joomla. It kept giving me headaches, so I decided it might be due to the fact that the version is outdated. However, it just seems like I'm lacking options - there is no Extention Manager, no Components-> Joomla updates, no nothing.

Could it be the case that Im not "the real" administrator, i.e. that I don't have full permission to modify stuff? At this point, it seems like I can only edit/publish/unpublish stuff.

Also, is there any alternative way I could do the update/change something for better?

Comment: In Joomla 3x "Admin" is called Super User. Check under Users->Manage that your account is a Super User.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably an Administrator and not the Super User, you can check your account at **Users**->**Manage**, that's why you don't have access to all Joomla functions.
You can try to manually update Joomla follow [this](https://docs.joomla.org/Updating_Joomla_(Manual_Method)) (not really sure if an Administrator even can) but i think that up the road you 'll need full access to make your life easier.